# Как правильно создать схему в Doctrine?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine2, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Все находится в докер контейнере.
Композер конфиг

```
{
    "name": "user/php",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.11.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/annotations": "1.13.2",
        "symfony/yaml": "^5.4",
        "symfony/cache": "^5.4"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "ryaev",
            "email": "n.ru"
        }
    ]
}
```

В папке config файлы
bootstrap.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$path = [__DIR__ . "/../src"];
$isDevMode = true;

$config = Setup::createAttributeMetadataConfiguration($path, $isDevMode);

$connection = [
  'dbname' => 'test',
  'user' => 'root',
  'password' => 123456,
  'host' => 'db',
  'driver' => 'pdo_mysql'
];

$entityManager = EntityManager::create($connection, $config);

cli-config.php
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;

require_once 'bootstrap.php';

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

Рядом с папкой config лежит src с моделью

```
<?php
/**
* @Entity @Table(name='users')
**/

class User
{
  /**@Id @Column(type='integer') @GeneratedValue**/
  private $id;
  /**@Name @Column(type='string')**/
  private $name;
  /**@email @Column(type='string')**/
  private $email;
  
  public function setName($name)
  {
    $this->name = $name;
  }

  public function setEmail($email)
  {
    $this->email = $email;
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return $this->name;
  }

  public function getEmail()
  {
    return $this->email;
  }
}
```

Когда пытаюсь создать схему vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create пишет

> [Warning] The use of this script is discouraged. See
> https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/tools.html#doctrine-console
> for instructions on bootstrapping the console runner.
>
> [OK] No Metadata Classes to process.